# ROS Launcher File Results in Error with roslaunch

Tags: ros, catkin

I have a ROS project that I'm trying out. I have the following folder structure:

```
catkin_ws
  - src
    - beginner_tutorials
      - src
        - listener.cpp
        - talker.cpp
      - config
        - config.conf
      - launch
        - my.launch
      - srv
        - ModifyText.srv
      - CMakeLists.txt
```

Assume that I have the remaining folders in the catkin_ws like the devel etc.,

Here is the CMakeLists.txt looks like:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(beginner_tutorials)

## Find catkin and any catkin packages
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS roscpp rospy std_msgs genmsg)

## Declare ROS messages and services
#add_message_files(FILES Num.msg)
add_service_files(FILES modifyText.srv)

## Generate added messages and services
generate_messages(DEPENDENCIES std_msgs)

## Declare a catkin package
catkin_package()

## Build talker and listener
include_directories(include ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS})

add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
target_link_libraries(talker ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(talker beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)

add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
target_link_libraries(listener ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
add_dependencies(listener beginner_tutorials_generate_messages_cpp)
```

Now when I tried to launch the listener and talker using the launcher file as below, I get the error as below:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~/Projects/ros-projects/catkin_ws$ roslaunch beginner_tutorials my.launch
... logging to /home/joesan/.ros/log/4df614ca-ebaa-11ea-b08a-3fbc143c4e1a/roslaunch-joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5-7071.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:37169/

SUMMARY
========

PARAMETERS
 * /rosdistro: noetic
 * /rosversion: 1.15.8

NODES
  /
    listener (beginner_tutorials/listener)
    talker (beginner_tutorials/talker)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

process[talker-1]: started with pid [7085]
RLException: Roslaunch got a 'No such file or directory' error while attempting to run:

gnome-terminal -e /home/joesan/Projects/ros-projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib/beginner_tutorials/listener __name:=listener __log:=/home/joesan/.ros/log/4df614ca-ebaa-11ea-b08a-3fbc143c4e1a/listener-2.log

Please make sure that all the executables in this command exist and have
executable permission. This is often caused by a bad launch-prefix.
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
[ INFO] [1598893286.274250713]: hello world 0
[talker-1] killing on exit
[listener-2] killing on exit
```

Here are the contents of my launch file my.launch:

```
<launch>
    <env name="ROSCONSOLE_CONFIG_FILE"
         value="$(find beginner_tutorials)/config/config.conf"/>
    <arg name = "frequency" default = "10" />
    <node pkg = "beginner_tutorials"
          type = "talker"
          name = "talker"
          output = "screen"
          args="$(arg frequency)"/>
    
    <node pkg = "beginner_tutorials"
          type = "listener"
          name = "listener"
          output = "screen"
          launch-prefix = "gnome-terminal -e"/>
</launch>
```

I can see that inside the devel folders, the binaries are located as below:

```
joesan@joesan-InfinityBook-S-14-v5:~/Projects/ros-projects/catkin_ws/devel/lib$ cd beginner_tutorials/
drwxrwxr-x joesan joesan     4 KB Mon Aug 31 18:44:39 2020  .
drwxrwxr-x joesan joesan     4 KB Mon Aug 31 18:44:37 2020  ..
.rwxrwxr-x joesan joesan 327.3 KB Mon Aug 31 18:44:39 2020  listener
.rwxrwxr-x joesan joesan 190.1 KB Mon Aug 31 18:44:39 2020  talker
```

Comment: Looks like there is no executable called ```listener``` available. How does your CMakeLists look like?

Comment: I have added the CMakeLists.txt for reference!

Comment: Why the launch prefix ```gnome-terminal -e```? Could you try to remove it?

Comment: That kind of fixed the issue, but I thought I could open that in a new window which is why I had that as an option to debug!

Comment: try "xterm -e"

I use that very often to launch my nodes in gdbserver

I use "xterm -e gdbserver :1234" as launch-prefix